# showing a sql coulmn data in a vb.net combobox

Tags: vb.net

I want to show all the data in a specific column in one combobox and my code is just showing the last data in the column here is the code i am using

```
Dim connectionstring As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=Enginee;Integrated Security=True"

Try
        Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim sqlquery As String
        connection.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Open")
        sqlquery = " Select PROJECT.PROJECT_CODE,PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME From PROJECT INNER JOIN ENGINEERS on ENGINEERS.ENGINEER_ID = ENGINEERS.ENGINEER_ID where ENGINEERS.FNAME = '" & Sign_In.TextBox1.Text & "' "

        Dim selectcommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = selectcommand.ExecuteReader
        Dim test As Boolean = reader.Read

        While test = True
            ComboBox1.Text = reader(0)
            TextBox1.Text = reader(1)
            test = reader.Read
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed")
    End Try
```

Comment: Use this ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader(0).ToString()) instead of ComboBox1.Text .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the .text of the ComboBox add the item.

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader(0));
```

Setting the Text value will just set what the current item is, not adding them to the dropdown list.